# Jquery on click change combo value

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a product with some colors details.
Eg: http://accommodationinbrasov.com/detail.asp?id=23#
when i click a color for that product i will like the value of select (frame) to change to that color.
anybody could get me on the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably store a list of colors in an array first.

Then, you can bind a change() handler for the select options, like this:

HTML:

```
<select id="products">
  <option value="0">Blue</option>
  <option value="1">Black</option>
  <option value="2">Red</option>
</select>
```

If you have an associative array, then you could replace the numbers by keys.

Then in JavaScript, you could do this:

```
$('#products').change(function() {
  $("option:selected", $(this)).each(function() {
     var index = $(this).val();
     $(this).css('backgroundColor', colorList[index]);
  });
})
```

where colorList is the array of colors.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have all color variations of that frame i.e. image of brown, red, white etc. frames as images.

For example your images could be named like:
/images/frame_1_brown.jpg
/images/frame_1_red.jpg
/images/frame_1_white.jpg

On the select you have something like this:

```
<select name="color">
   <option value="/images/frame_1_brown.jpg" selected="selected">Brown</option>
   <option value="/images/frame_1_red.jpg">Red</option>
   <option value="/images/frame_1_white.jpg">White</option>
</select>
```

You have an image tag like:

```
<img src="/images/frame_1_brown.jpg" alt="Glasses" id="product-image"/>
```

Then the javascript will look like:

```
$('select[name=color]').change(function(){
   $('#product-image').attr('src', $(this).val());
})
```

Assuming that you use jQuery of course.

Basically this will change the image's src attribute when you change the selection of the dropdown.

Comment: Not sure if you guys got my problem... I want when i click on the image to change the select value not the opposed...

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        a, a:link,a:hover, a:active, a:visited{
            text-decoration: none;

            color:#000;
        }
        a:hover{
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        div{
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a id="one" href="#" class="clickable"><img src="" alt="one" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a id="two" href="#" class="clickable"><img src="" alt="two" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a id="three" href="#" class="clickable"><img src="" alt="three" border="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    <div>
        <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
            <option value="three">three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.clickable').click(function(){
               val = $(this).attr("id");
               $("#dropdown").val(val);
           });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this is the answer to my problem